# Сокращение строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Строка сокращается, если диапазон больше `{1,40}`. Но если меньше, пропадает.

```
preg_match('/<title[^>]*?>(.{1,40})(.*?)<\/title>/uis', $card, $title);
echo $title[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = substr($card, 0, 40);
```

Comment: Ещё лучше - `mb_substr($card, 0, 40);` , т.к. substr будет некорректно обрабатывать кодировки типо utf8.

Comment: @adudnik.ru  впервые слышу